# Threejs gltfLoader make model clickable

Tags: model, onclicklistener, gltf

I am new to threejs and now trying to make this work since ....

I am loading a GLTF with mappings (jpg) into threejs.

I can't find a way to make the loaded model clickable.

Can you please show, how to make this model clickable (single or double click and touch)
and call a js-function ?

this is my scene:

[threejs-model-link](https://www.test.till.graphics/TEST-ID-CARD/)

```
function sendMail() {
    //$('#myModal').modal('show');
    alert('click');
}

import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r127/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r127/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r127/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

let model;
let object = new THREE.Object3D();
let raycaster, mouse,  intersects, gltfobject;

function main() {
    
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas , antialias: true});

    const fov = 60;
    const aspect = 1;  // the canvas default
    const near = 0.6;
    const far = 1200;
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
    camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
    controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
    controls.update();

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

    //raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    //mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    //let pickableMeshes = [];


    
    {
        const skyColor = 0xB1E1FF;  // light blue
        const groundColor = 0xFFFFFF;  // brownish orange
        const intensity = 0.9;
        const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(skyColor, groundColor, intensity);
        scene.add(light);
    }

    {
        const color = 0xFFFFFF;
        const intensity = 0.3;
        const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
        light.position.set(5, 10, 2);
        scene.add(light);
        scene.add(light.target);
    }

    function frameArea(sizeToFitOnScreen, boxSize, boxCenter, camera) {
        
        const halfSizeToFitOnScreen = sizeToFitOnScreen * 0.5;
        const halfFovY = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov * .5);
        const distance = halfSizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY);
        // compute a unit vector that points in the direction the camera is now
        // in the xz plane from the center of the box
        const direction = (new THREE.Vector3())
        .subVectors(camera.position, boxCenter)
        .multiply(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1))
        .normalize();

        // move the camera to a position distance units way from the center
        // in whatever direction the camera was from the center already
        camera.position.copy(direction.multiplyScalar(distance).add(boxCenter));

        // pick some near and far values for the frustum that
        // will contain the box.
        camera.near = boxSize / 100;
        camera.far = boxSize * 100;

        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        // point the camera to look at the center of the box
        camera.lookAt(boxCenter.x, boxCenter.y, boxCenter.z);
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); // Update size
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight; // Update aspect ratio
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); // Apply changes
    });

    {

        const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();

        gltfLoader.load('my_test_id_card_app.gltf', (gltf) => {
            
            const root = gltf.scene;
            scene.add(root);


            // compute the box that contains all the stuff
            // from root and below
            const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(root);
            const boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
            const boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

            // set the camera to frame the box
            frameArea(boxSize * 2, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);

            scene.rotation.z = 20;
            //scene.rotation.x -= 0.002;
            scene.rotation.y = 20;

            // update the Trackball controls to handle the new size
            controls.maxDistance = boxSize * 10;
            controls.target.copy(boxCenter);
            controls.update();
        });

    }

    
    

    function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
        const canvas = renderer.domElement;
        const width = canvas.clientWidth;
        const height = canvas.clientHeight;
        const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
        if (needResize) {
            renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
        }
        return needResize;
    }

    function render() {
        if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
        const canvas = renderer.domElement;
        camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    // Update trackball controls
    controls.update();

    // Constantly rotate box
    scene.rotation.z -= 0.002;
    scene.rotation.x -= 0.004;
    scene.rotation.y -= 0.006;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}


    

main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a pointerevent like `pointerup` and then use the [`Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=raycast#api/en/core/Raycaster) like you already tried.

This is the relevant code:

```js
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('pointerup', (event) => {
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth - renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect().x) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight + renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect().y) * 2 + 1;
    
    console.log(mouse.x, mouse.y);

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      console.log("Model clicked.")
    }
});
```

It is based on this [ThreeJS example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d39d82999f0ac5cdd1b4eb9f4aba3f9626f32ab6/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html#L136).

First we need to map the mouse coordinates to the rectangle between (1,1) (1, -1) (-1, -1) and (-1, 1).

Then we use the mapped mouse coordinates to `setFromCamera` the raycaster.

After that use the raycaster to find all objects that intersect with the ray `raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true)`. Note that `recursive` is set to `true` in [`intersectObjects`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObjects), because we also want to detect a click on nested objects.

Lastly here is a full [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuap2c4j/1/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its just working like it should do. sepp.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quickest way to load a gltf model and display a message when it is selected using the latest version of Three.js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Three.js GLTF Model and Raycaster Example</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
      canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r128/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r128/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Set up the scene, camera, and renderer
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // Create a grid
      var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
      scene.add(gridHelper);

      // Create a raycaster for interaction
      var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
      var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

      // Load GLTF model
      var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
      loader.load('path/to/model.gltf', function (gltf) {
        var model = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(model);

        // Position and scale the model
        model.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        model.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
      });

      // Handle mouse click
      function onMouseClick(event) {
        // Calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
        mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

        // Update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

        // Check for intersections
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {
          alert('Clicked on the model!');
        }
      }

      // Add event listener for mouse click
      window.addEventListener('click', onMouseClick, false);

      // Position the camera
      camera.position.z = 5;

      // Render the scene
      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```